# Advertising ID warning in Google Play

Tags: google-play, warnings

I have Advertising ID warming in Google Play due to usage of old TapJoy plugin.

I have updated app with new TapJoy plugin but warning has not disappeared.
Today I completely removed TapJoy upload app and warning is still there.

I have unzipped APK, decompiled DEX in JAR in Source Code and there is no TapJoy code.

How much should I wait for warning to disappear? 
IS there way to force google to rescan apps?

I have that warning in Google Play and in Admob and I am willing to fix, remove it.